# screen mirroring to chromecast

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I want to know how to mirror the whole Android screen to Chromecast via code without using the Google Home app.

Here's what I want from Google Home that I want to automate.

"Casting your Android screen lets you mirror your Android device to the TV so you can enjoy your content exactly as you see it on your mobile device—only bigger."

From: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en

Thank you

Regards,
Ezekiel

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast Help Forum Reply:

> Hello, thanks for taking the time to post your issue.
>
> What you are seeking to accomplish is not supported using Chromecast